# Extract text from image using pytesseract in two-tones background

Tags: python, text, python-tesseract, threshold, image-thresholding

I'm trying to extract text from an image using pytesseract on Python. This is the image where I want to extract the text:

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqNnR.png)

This is the image after applying threshold:

[Image with threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQqlX.png)

Console Output:

```
20 hours

20 hours

Bhours
```

[Console Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhMSO.png)

This is the code I'm using:

```
from pytesseract import *
import cv2

path = r"path where image is located"             #path of image
folderPath = r"path for saving output image" 

grey_image = cv2.imread(path,0)                   #import image

_,bt = cv2.threshold(grey_image, 150 ,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)   #variable means binary threshold

cv2.imwrite(folderPath + "\\" + "test.png", bt)   #Saving result

imageout = pytesseract.image_to_string(bt)        #Convert image to text

print(imageout)                                   #Print text in console
```

I've been trying different ranges of thresholding but still can't get a precise output.

What do you suggest for getting a precise result?

Comment: Try [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization)
 or [adaptive threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding)

Comment: I already tried with adaptative threshold, it was worst (- laugh-). I'll try with Otsu's threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are dealing with an image containing white characters over a dark background, it is recommended to invert it prior using pytesseract.

This is done using `inverted_grey_image  = cv2.bitwise_not(grey_image)`.

You may then adjust the threshold in `threshold`:  `_,bt =  cv2.threshold(inverted_grey_image, 140 ,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`

Below is the full code:

```
from pytesseract import *
import cv2

path = r"path where image is located"             #path of image
folderPath = r"path for saving output image" 

grey_image = cv2.imread(path,0)                   #import image

inverted_grey_image = cv2.bitwise_not(grey_image)

_,bt = cv2.threshold(inverted_grey_image, 140 ,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)   #variable means binary threshold

cv2.imwrite(folderPath + "/" + "test.png", bt)   #Saving result

imageout = pytesseract.image_to_string(bt)        #Convert image to text


print(imageout)
```

It returns:

> 20 hours
>
> 20 hours
>
> 3 hours

**EDIT:** I am currently dealing with a similar OCR problem: you may want to check [this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71442585/adjusting-pytesseract-parameters) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll do that!

Comment: I did what you suggest, but still, it's not perfect. There are some numbers that can't be imported from the image. I'll try to apply what you have in your post.